# Same KSH script run in test env but fails in production

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, unix, ksh

I run the below script in a reference env and get the correct output in the output file, but when I run the same in production the output file is empty. 
I tried debugging the using set -x, and understand that the for loop is not getting executed in the prod env.
please suggest what might be the issue.

```
#!/bin/ksh
DIR=/some/log/dir/error
DATE=$1
OUTPUT=/some/logs/dir/scripts/output/output.csv

. /calling/env/setupscript.ksh 

for file in $(find $DIR 2>/dev/null| grep $ASOF | grep -i something1 | grep -vi someotherthing2 | grep -iv someotherthing3 | grep -vi someotherthing4 | grep -vi someotherthing4 )
do
  echo "Checking file $file..."
  if [[ -z "$DONE" ]] then
     head -1 $file | read line
     echo "File name;Filter name;Type;Scenario;$line" > $OUTPUT.tmp
     DONE=1
  fi
  fullfile=$file
  file=$(basename $file)
  file=${file#SPR_RPT_}
  file=${file#SPR_BY__}
  echo $file | awk -F_ '{ print $(NF-2)" "$(NF-1) }' | read type scen
  filter=${file%%_$type\_*}
  grep ERROR $fullfile | while read line
  do
    echo "$(basename $fullfile);$filter;$type;$scen;$line" >> ${OUTPUT}.tmp
  done
done
```

Comment: Did you try to see if the "find...|grep..|grep....." statement returned any value on the production server ?

Comment: @Andre_Gelinas : Yes, I did. I tried the complete "find" statement redirecting the output to a file instead of /dev/null/ and it returns approx. 60K results.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "redirecting the output to a file instead of /dev/null/" ... In your script you only redirect StdErr to /dev/null, so shouldn't make a difference on the command line. But then again, maybe I misunderstand your meaning.

Comment: apologies for confusion. I used this "find $DIR >/some/dir/some/file.txt "

Comment: Ok, but with all the grep statements as well since they modify the result. Basically the idea is that if the loop has no fuel, it won't go.

Comment: There is too much code that might work different. Try to make it small. Did you see output of `echo "Checking file $file..."`  for all files?

Comment: @AndreGelinas applying all the greps, leaves us with approx. 900 files, redirected that output to another file and confirmed.

Comment: @WalterA. Yes, the echo output is available in non-prod host but not on the production host.